# Error while submitting a paid app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I get the next error in iTunes Connect while I try to submit my paid app, that doesn't use any entitlements(In-App Purchase, Game Center, iCloud, Push Notifications, and the rest of them), even if the In-App Purchase and Game Center are by default ticked when the app id is created, and the error is:

***Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy URL for [English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary.***

Please help me sort this out, as I don't know what should I change in my binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project settings, click on the tab Capabilities, and make sure all of the switches are on OFF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9meUm.png

If these are all off then you must have toggled it somewhere else when setting up the app. You should be able to get around it by logging onto iTunesConnect and making sure you have filled out the Privacy Policy URL (which will actually say its optional)

Comment: I have toggled the off but it still doesn't work, how should the Privacy Policy URL looks like, not the url but the content.

Comment: Here is one we did for a restaurant and bar app: http://theinsiderapp.co.nz/privacypolicy.html. But you can just use the same URL as your Support URL if you don't have one I am sure.